# Exactly how does a linked list behave when passed into a function?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

Here is my Node class:

```
class Node:

 def __init__(self, value):
   self.value = value
   self.next = None

 def __repr__(self):
   if self.next == None:
     return 'Node({})'.format(repr(self.value))
   else:
     return 'Node({}, {})'.format(
       repr(self.value), repr(self.next))
```

And here is my method m:

```
def m(lnk):
   while lnk and lnk.next:
       lnk.next = lnk.next.next
       lnk = lnk.next
   print(lnk)
```

I then run the following code:

```
lnk = Node(1)
lnk.next = Node(2)
lnk.next.next = Node(3)
m(lnk)
print(lnk)
```

The first output is Node(3) and the second output is Node(1, Node(3)). I understand the first output, but it's the second output that I don't really get. Why is the Node(1) still there? I thought lnk would be passed in as a reference, and therefore would change and have the same values as it did in my function. However, this is not happening, and I don't understand why.

Comment: I haven't fully analyzed the effects yet, but the line `lnk.next = lnk.next.next` in your `m` function probably doesn't do what you want.  You could just remove it, and I bet you'd get better results.

Comment: It's not that I want my function to do something, I'm just trying to figure out why it does what it does.

Comment: Yes, but I assume you want m to walk the tree and print the last link.  The thing is, you're mutating the tree.  When you pass `lnk` into it, you set lnk.next, which was 2, to be lnk.next.next, which is 3.

Comment: I thought my function would make lnk equal to Node(3). However, lnk is instead Node(1, Node(3)). That's what I'm not really understanding here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem right now is that your m function doesn't do what it's supposed to.  Change it by deleting the line `lnk.next = lnk.next.next`:

```
def m(lnk):
   while lnk and lnk.next:
       lnk = lnk.next
   print(lnk)
```

Then, you'll get the following results:

```
>>> m(lnk)
Node(3)
>>> print(lnk)
Node(1, Node(2, Node(3)))
```

So, what's doing what?

`__repr__` says that if you're the last part of the list, return "Node(#)" where # is the value.  If you're not the last part of the list, return the list of Nodes below you.

The modified `m` function will now simply print the last node in the list.

Look in detail at what your current setup is and what your `m` function does:

Current:  lnk = {'value': 1, 'next': {'value': 2, 'next' : {'value': 3, 'next': None}}}

The first pass of your loop through `m` takes the object you passed in, called `lnk`, which is defined as above, and changes it so lnk = {'value': 1, 'next': {'value': 3, 'next': None}}  (because of the lnk.next = lnk.next.next).  On your second pass in the loop, the `lnk` variable has changed.  It's no longer pointing to the same object; it's pointing to the object {'value': 3, 'next': None}, and the loop stops, since 'next' is None.

Note that this modified your linked list, and I don't think that was the intent.

The reference Evan points you to is a good one.  As you read up on things, you'll see that the variable name inside the function is local.  It starts by refering to the Node(1) object you create, but when you assign it to something else, it's no longer referring to that object.  It's not passed by value, though, because changes you make internal to that object (such as setting lnk.next.next) do still persist.

When you create your initial linked list, you need to use the `.next.next` syntax to avoid making temporary variables for each Node.  You could also have constructed your list like this:

```
node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
linked_list = node1
```

Now, if you want to update `lnk` to point to the tail of the list, you need to return your local variable.  `m` and its usage should be something like this:

```
def m(node):
    while node and node.next:
        node = node.next
    return node

tail = m(lnk)
```

Note that I renamed the argument of `m` to be `node`.  This should help you avoid confusion about where `lnk` is being set or modified.  Realize that your results would still be the same if you kept m modifying the list.  Even if it's named `node`, the line `node.next = node.next.next` would still have modified your variable named `lnk` in the higher scope.

On a style note, I would highly recommend never naming a function `m`.  Give it a name such as `get_tail` or `get_leaf`, so it's clear what the function does.  At least some of your confusion came from not having a clear definition of what m is supposed to do.

If you **must** modify the `lnk` variable internal to the function (the variable itself, not the contents), you can do it using globals, but this is almost always a bad idea, and shouldn't be done.  (Because people are used to variables behaving the way they do, and changing the behavior makes the code harder to maintain.  In this case, most people expect operations on linked lists to not be destructive unless it's semantically obvious that they are intended to be, e.g. `pop`.)

```
def m():
    global lnk
    while lnk and lnk.next:
        lnk = lnk.next
```

Answer (score 2):

[Variables in Python are not passed by reference, but by assignment.](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) It is effectively the same as passing a pointer variable in C or C++: if you change the fields on a mutable object inside a function, the changes will then be visible in the calling scope, but if you change the identity of the variable itself, it won't be.